# Jquery select2 is not working for multiple 'optgroup'

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Jquery `select2`, I am having a select box like this

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="address">
    <optgroup class="op1" label="Maryland">
        <optgroup class="op2" label="Perth">
            <option value="West Baltimore Street, Baltimore, MD">West Baltimore Street, Baltimore, MD</option>
            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="Njurunda, Sweden">Njurunda, Sweden</option>
        </optgroup>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup class="op1" label="Kerala">
        <optgroup class="op2" label="Ernakulam">
            <option value="Ernakulam, Kerala, India">Ernakulam, Kerala, India</option>
            <option value="Muvattupuzha, Kerala, India">Muvattupuzha, Kerala, India</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup class="op2" label="Idukki">
            <option value="Thodupuzha, Kerala, India">Thodupuzha, Kerala, India</option>
        </optgroup>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

The output I get with `select2`

[image]

And my actual output should be like this

[image]

That is `<optgroup class="op1" label="kerala">` is missing . 
Any idea how do this?

Comment: use single level optgroup nesting.

Answer (score -2):

looks like it has unclosed html tag, validate your html. validated markup looks like this

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="address">
    <optgroup class="op1" label="Maryland"></optgroup>
    <optgroup class="op2" label="Perth"></optgroup>
    <option value="West Baltimore Street, Baltimore, MD">West Baltimore Street, Baltimore, MD</option>
    <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="Njurunda, Sweden">Njurunda, Sweden</option>
    <optgroup class="op1" label="Kerala"></optgroup>
    <optgroup class="op2" label="Ernakulam"></optgroup>
    <option value="Ernakulam, Kerala, India">Ernakulam, Kerala, India</option>
    <option value="Muvattupuzha, Kerala, India">Muvattupuzha, Kerala, India</option>
    <optgroup class="op2" label="Idukki"></optgroup>
    <option value="Thodupuzha, Kerala, India">Thodupuzha, Kerala, India</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) should wrap option lists.  Moreover, as per [HTML 5 std](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-optgroup-element) the closing tag is not required.